# jersey - StreamingOutput as Response entity

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

I had implemented streaming output in my Jersey Resource class.

```
@GET
@Path("xxxxx")
@Produces(BulkConstants.TEXT_XML_MEDIA_TYPE})   
public Response getFile() {

    FeedReturnStreamingOutput sout = new FeedReturnStreamingOutput();
    response = Response.ok(sout).build();
    return response;
}

class FeedReturnStreamingOutput implements StreamingOutput {

    public FeedReturnStreamingOutput()

    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream outputStream)  {
        //write into Output Stream
    }
}
```

The problem is eventhough a response is sent back from the resource before FeedReturnStreamingOutput is called Jersey client waits until FeedReturnStreamingOutput execution is completed.

Client Code :

```
Client client = Client.create();

ClientResponse response = webResource
    //headers
    .get(ClientResponse.class);

//The codes underneath executes after FeedReturnStreamingOutput is executed which undermines the necessity of streaming

OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("c:\\test\\feedoutput5.txt");
System.out.println(new Date() + " : Reached point A");

if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
    System.out.println(new Date() + " : Reached point B");
    InputStream io = response.getEntityInputStream();

    byte[] buff = new byte[1024000];
    int count = 0;

    while ((count = io.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) != -1) {
        os.write(buff, 0, count);
    }

    os.close();
    io.close();

} else {
    System.out.println("Response code :" + response.getStatus());
}

System.out.println("Time taken -->> "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)+" ms");
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The problem is the buffering `OutputStream` that Jersey uses to buffer the entity in order to determine the Content-Length header. The size of the buffer default to 8 kb. You disable the buffering if you want, or just change the size of the buffer, with the property

> [`ServerProperties.OUTBOUND_CONTENT_LENGTH_BUFFER`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#OUTBOUND_CONTENT_LENGTH_BUFFER)
>
> An integer value that defines the buffer size used to buffer server-side response entity in order to determine its size and set the value of HTTP "Content-Length" header.
>
> If the entity size exceeds the configured buffer size, the buffering would be cancelled and the entity size would not be determined. Value less or equal to zero disable the buffering of the entity at all.
>
> This property can be used on the server side to override the outbound message buffer size value - default or the global custom value set using the "jersey.config.contentLength.buffer" global property.
>
> The default value is 8192.

Here's an example

```
@Path("streaming")
public class StreamingResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/octet-stream")
    public Response getStream() {
        return Response.ok(new FeedReturnStreamingOutput()).build();
    }

    public static class FeedReturnStreamingOutput implements StreamingOutput {

        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream output)
                throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    output.write(String.format("Hello %d\n", i).getBytes());
                    output.flush();
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  throw new RuntimeException(e); }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the result without setting the property

[image]

And here's the result after setting the property value to `0`

```
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        ...
        property(ServerProperties.OUTBOUND_CONTENT_LENGTH_BUFFER, 0);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great solution. A thing I found just now - this only works if you have a newline character at the end of your input :)

Comment: @Paul You mean without setting `OUTBOUND_CONTENT_LENGTH_BUFFER = 0` we can't actually stream anything ? i.e. unless we set that buffer to 0, it would buffer all into the memory and then flush that out ? (which might cause memory out of bound if the response is large)

Comment: @Paul Samsotha is there any way to do it the standard Java/Jakarta EE way? I use the jakarta-ee-api dependency and cannot find the ResourceConfig class, I guess because it belongs to Jersey?

Comment: where is the "property" method coming from?

Comment: @DragonMoon ResourceConfig

Comment: Is there a way to set this on a per-method basis rather than for the entire server?

Answer (score 1):

Try invoking `outputStream.flush()` from the method `FeedReturnStreamingOutput.write(...)` every X number of bytes written to the output stream or something like that.

I guess the buffer of the connection is not filled with the data you are returning. So the service does not return anything until Jersey invokes `outputStream.close()`.

In my case, I have a service that streams data and I am doing it exactly as you: by returning `Response.ok(<instance of StreamingOutput>).build();`.

My service returns data from a database and I invoke `outputStream.flush()` after writing each row to the output stream.

I know that the service streams data because I can see the client begins receiving data before the service has finished sending the entire result.

Comment: I added outputstream.flush everytime I write into the output stream. Doesn't makes any difference

Comment: @user1016496 How do you know that the service is not streaming?
Could it be that the service is actually streaming the data, but the client is not writing what it obtains in streaming mode?

Answer (score 1):

Either your response is too small and never gets [chunked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) so the server flushes the entire request at once. Or you have a server side issue were your jax-rs library is awaiting to have the complete stream before flushing.

However this looks more like a client problem. And you seem to be using an old version of jersey-client.

Also that `.get(ClientResponse.class)` looks fishy.

Try using the JAX-RS standard as it is today ([at least in the client](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/migration.html#mig-client-api)):

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/");
Response response = target.path("path/to/resource").request().get();
```

While having jersey client 2.17 in the classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
</dependency>
```