# StreamingOutput not producing output immediately

Tags: java, spring, java-stream, jax-rs

I am using [StreamingOutput](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html) to stream output from GET service. However, even if partial output is written to outputStream, it is not displayed on Browser/cURL output.
Data is displayed only after entire output is written to stream. In below code I have added `Thread.sleep` to simulate the delay in producing the data.

How can we make sure the data is available to client as soon as it is written to stream?

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import java.io.*;

@Path("/stream")
@Produces("text/plain")
public class StreamResource {

    @GET
    public Response streamExample(){
        StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
            public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
                for (int i = 0; i < 60 ; i++){
                    writer.write(i + " ");
                    writer.flush();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000); // Just to simulate delay in producing data
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
               
            }
        };
        return Response.ok(stream).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're using Jersey, you might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34358215/2587435) out.

Comment: Great answer. Worked for me. Thanks @PaulSamsotha