# Jersey: StreamingOutput in a chunked fashion without setting OUTBOUND_CONTENT_LENGTH_BUFFER to 0?

Tags: java, jersey

I am using Jersey to stream "chunked" output, and my client wishes to read and display partial results as they are streamed.

Here is example code of what I am doing:

```
@Path("streaming")
public class StreamingResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/octet-stream")
    public Response getStream() {
        return Response.ok(new FeedReturnStreamingOutput()).build();
    }

    public static class FeedReturnStreamingOutput implements StreamingOutput {

        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream output)
                throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    output.write(String.format("Hello %d\n", i).getBytes());
                    output.flush();
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  throw new RuntimeException(e); }
        }
    }
}
```

As described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34358215/2452569, I have to add a configuration value to my server config like so, otherwise the content is not flushed as it is written:

```
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        ...
        property(ServerProperties.OUTBOUND_CONTENT_LENGTH_BUFFER, 0);
    }
}
```

This Jersey server is part of a large commercial application that, up until now, just didn't have any endpoints that required this kind of streaming.

Since the `OUTBOUND_CONTENT_LENGTH_BUFFER` setting is an Application-wide setting, I'm worried that setting it to zero will have negative ramifications in our customer base. I've scoured the web to try to figure out what those could be, but I'm having a hard time discerning anything concrete.

So, two questions:

1. Is there any way (still using Jersey) to avoid setting this Application-wide config variable and still be able to stream from one endpoint?
2. If there's no other way, can anyone describe the potential negative ramifications?

Answer (score 0):

> Since the OUTBOUND_CONTENT_LENGTH_BUFFER setting is a server-wide setting

This is an Application-scoped setting. Each Application has its own set of settings and won't affect other Applications. That is if you are in the standard Application Server that supports one application per one war.

You might be on another environment that might even support multiple Applications per runtime (e.g. Helidon), but it is rare to use more than one Application in a single runtime instance.

Comment: I've changed my question to say "Application-wide" instead of "server-wide". I still need to solve the problem-- I can't modify my codebase to have more than one application.

Comment: So if you have just one app, it does not affect the other applications, does it?

Comment: I only have one application. I don’t want to affect all endpoints in the application, that’s my problem.

Comment: Maybe you want to use [ChunkedOutput](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/async.html#chunked-output) instead?

Comment: I saw that, I don’t see how to use it in the context of an application like I am showing in the original post. If you can post a working example, that would be helpful.